# Creating a 20x20 grid JPanel (JPanels in each grid box) recursively but reference each box?

Tags: java, swing

Question sounds terrible, I apologize for that.

Simply put I'm attempting to create a 20x20 'grid' of squares that are either all black or all white, mimicking pixels.  I know how to recursively create the grid as so I don't have 400 variables (as in as apposed to adding 400 JPanels one by one), I'm just unsure how I can reference a specific box later on to change the color state.

I'm thinking of perhaps having a white background with a Grid line drawn over it (on a jPanel).  Then creating another JPanel with a 20x20 gridlayout and having a method that given a certain input (eg 18x9) it would add a black jpanel at that grid.

Is my thinking correct in this?  I'm going to go ahead with it anyways but perhaps some pointers would be helpful as I'm still new to Java.  Or is there another approach I could use instead?  I've been told to dump swing and move onto JavaFX (even though it implements swing) as it's much more versatile, but I'm not ready to go that far just yet.

Thanks!

EDIT:  And I suppose I should mention this isn't going to be an 'editable' output per say. It'll draw it once in otherwords.  So I don't need to worry about hiding panels later on as I'll just be starting a new output then.

Answer (score 0):

> I'm just unsure how I can reference a specific box later on to change the color state.

Just keep a reference to all the components that you add in the grid to an ArrayList.

> having a method that given a certain input (eg 18x9)

So to reference that component you get the index to use in the ArrayList:

```
int index = (18 * 9) - 1;
JPanel panel = list.get(index);
panel.setBackground(...);
```